# Enable static website on Azure Storage not showing in the list of options

Tags: azure, azureportal

I would like to have a go at using Azure storage to host my static website.

Following this tutorial I have got to the point here I need to enable static website.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host

[image]

However when I go to do this.. the option of static website isn't in the list.

Can anyone help me?  I have tried different regions and account kinds but none of them are showing the option.

As shown in my screenshot below I have set ip up with Storage V2 (General Purpose V2) as per the docs, but still do not get the option.

[image]

Comment: did i understand the question correct?

Comment: I think so, it wasn't me who downvoted your answer.  I have it setup as GPv2 if you look at the screenshot so not sure why it's not showing

Comment: what type of subscription you have

Comment: Pay as you go subscription

Comment: oh is it premium, gaurav's answer should help you

Comment: thank you for your help, it's really appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem I believe is your combination of account's `Performance` and `Replication`. Currently it is set as `Premium LRS` which does not support static website.

Please create a new `Storage V2` account with `Standard` performance tier and `LRS` replication and you should be able to see the option of enabling static website.

Comment: This was my issue, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if Account Kind is Storage (general purpose v1) than also you will not able to see Static web site feature.

[image]

Create a storage account with Account Kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

[image]